# Difference between DXTREME and PhoneGap

Tags: cordova, chart.js, phonejs, devextreme

Can anyone help me with what are the differences between DXTREME and PhoneGap?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Phonegap is free
With phonegap you can build hybrid apps (apps you can sell on the app stores and access to native capabilities)

DevExtreme is just for creating webapps or web sites, and it can be combined with phonegap.

So they are completely different things, but they can be combined.

EDIT: Now DevExtreme has built in phonegap integration: 
http://js.devexpress.com/MobileDevelopment/StoreReadyApps/

Comment: Can DXTREME be used to make iPhone apps?

Comment: according to their web, yes.  Multi-Channel Experiences

From Windows 8 and the iPad to iPhone and Android smartphones, take advantage of new digital touch points by creating the apps that that feel as though they were designed expressly for the device. Apache Cordova (PhoneGap) support means you can run your touch based applications natively on all target devices. You can even submit your applications to the Apple App Store or the Google Play Store.

Comment: You create the HTML,CSS and javascript with DXTREME and then convert it to "native" with phonegap

Answer (score 4):

DXTREME includes PhoneJS and ChartJS frameworks as well as Visual Studio 2010/2012 intergration tools (http://help.devexpress.com/DXTREME).

PhoneGap is a framework allowing you to access native device capabilities (accelerometer, camera, etc.) from JavaScript.

You can build native packages (iOS/Android) directly from Visual Studio with DXTREME installed (http://help.devexpress.com/DevExtreme/Howto/Packaging#Build_Package_for_Android).

You can also create a zip file ready for PhoneGap Build (since the 13.1 release).

Answer (score 3):

DXTREME is a product of DevExpress which is built on PhoneJS and ChartJS which are Javascript Libraries. DXTREME have their own Templates which can be integrated with Visual Studio. 
DXTREME also provides various Widgets that can be utilized. Moreover you can develop many types of Hybrid Apps with DXTREME which can also be called as Cross Platform Mobile App.
DXTREME supports Knockout JS, which means you can have MVVM pattern for UI Development.

But with DXTREME, you cannot utilize Device Hardware and thats where Phonegap comes in picture. Phonegap provides API with the help of which the DXTREME can access Device Hardware.
Phonegap is an Free and Open Source Framework that is used to develop Cross Platform Mobile Apps using Standardise Web API's.